# how to get a list map from firebase into a table in flutter

Tags: flutter, list, firebase, datatables

[photo one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OAl5.jpg)
[photo two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSKYb.jpg)

Iknow that we should use data model to get the tables data from firebase but i am not sure how to get the data into a map list inside a map list.
if anyone knows the answer please help us.

Itried many ways but Iwas getting errors.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example demonstrating how to fetch a list of **users** from the `user` collection and map it to the `user.dart` **POJO** class.

```dart
CollectionReference<User> get usersRef => fireStore.collection(path).withConverter<User>(
            fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => User.fromMap(snapshot.data()!),
            toFirestore: (item, _) => User.toMap(),
          );

Future<List<User>> getUsersList(CollectionReference<User> colRef) async {
    final data = await colRef.get().then((value) => value.docs);
    return data.map((e) => e.toPojo()).toList();
  }


extension _QueryDocumentParser on QueryDocumentSnapshot<User> {
  User toPojo() {
    final document = data();
    return document;
  }
}
```